# 7404 NOT gate LC oscillator

Tags: oscillator, logic-gates

I have found [this](http://hanssummers.com/plugins/content/plugin_jw_sig/showthumb.php?img=polyphase/vfo/osc.gif&width=2000&height=2000&quality=100) 7404 LC oscilator schematic online.

[image]

How does it work? I know that you can connect the input and out of a NOT gate and it will oscillate at a very high freq, dependant on parasitics and transition freq. of the gate.
In this case, does the 470k provide feedback required for oscillations or do those small 5pF caps provide 180deg of phase shift for it to work as a regular oscillator?

Comment: That circuit makes little sense as both the capacitor at the input and the output of the left NOT gate are connected to the same node. They can't, by definition, have any impact on the circuit below.

Comment: Also, as 5pF is in the range of the capacitance of adjacent breadboard columns, I think that circuit had been *fiddled*, then written down *as is* instead of developing it reasonably.

Comment: this circuit may depend on the propagation delay of the inverter.

Answer (score 1):

The 74ACT04 is a buffered (3-stage) inverter with TTL-compatible input thresholds.

The intention of the 470K resistor is to bias the inverter, however it will not have a stable bias because of the three stages. Normally we want to use an unbuffered inverter in such a role.

The idea of the originator is to have a tank circuit in the AC feedback to try to have it oscillate at one frequency, but this circuit is just as likely to squeg or ring during transitions at multiple frequencies simultaneously, and parasitics are likely to play a major role in what it does.

I don't think this is a reliable, predictable circuit.

Edit: for more information on using unbuffered inverters, see [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza043/szza043.pdf) TI application note.

Comment: The 74LCX04 made a pretty good oscillator using a crystal and DC feedback bias.

Comment: Yes, this kind of thing was pretty common with *some* inverter and a crystal, even in applications needing decent precision (for example ham radio harmonic marker generators).  The issues seem to be more with the selection of the particular inverter, and of course an LC circuit doesn't give the same behavior as a crystal.

Comment: Is it possible to make a tunable LC oscillator using basic 74xx or 4xxx series logic gates?

Comment: The unbuffered inverters can be biased as an amplifier and used to make an LC or crystal oscillator. See edit above.